# How to deploy different jars for different database runtimes with maven?

Tags: maven

I have different maven profiles and spring profiles for different databases: mysql, postgresql. Setting the maven profile adds the corresponding dependencies. Setting the spring profile adds the corresponding spring properties at runtime. I'd like to maintain one code base and deploy two different artifacts to my repository.

I'd like to generate the following jars: `${project.artifactId}-${target.database}-${project.version}`.

I have tried using classifiers but seems you can not configure the deploy plugin for them. Seems like you have to override properties from the command line. And with this approach the generated file name would be: `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${target.database}` (given that the classifier is named after `${target.database}`).

Is this at all possible to be configured within the pom and issuing standard maven commands only overriding the profiles?

If not, what would be the best approach?

## Edit: Add POM

In summary the POM defines per environment profile: dev, int, uat and pro; and per database profiles (orthogonal to the previous ones): mysql, postgresql. The important profiles here are the database profiles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.byteflair</groupId>
<artifactId>oauth2-server</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-RC1</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.byteflair.oauth.server.Oauth2ServerApp</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-security.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
    <sonar.version>2.7.1</sonar.version>
    <spock.version>1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-2</spock.version>
    <keystore.path>${project.build.directory}/keystore.jks</keystore.path>
    <unit.skip>false</unit.skip>
    <int.skip>false</int.skip>
    <docker.skip>false</docker.skip>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>mysql</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>mysql</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <classifier>mysql</classifier>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.15.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <images>
                            <image>
                                <!--docker  run &#x002d;&#x002d;name mensosdb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:3.0.8-->
                                <alias>oauthdb</alias>
                                <name>mysql:5.5</name>
                                <run>
                                    <env>
                                        <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>password</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                                        <MYSQL_USER>oauth_server</MYSQL_USER>
                                        <MYSQL_PASSWORD>password</MYSQL_PASSWORD>
                                        <MYSQL_DATABASE>oauth_db</MYSQL_DATABASE>
                                    </env>
                                    <ports>
                                        <port>3306:3306</port>
                                    </ports>
                                    <wait>
                                        <log>mysqld: ready for connections.</log>
                                        <time>20000</time>
                                    </wait>
                                </run>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                        <skip>${docker.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-containers</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-containers</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.36</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>postgresql</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>postgresql</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <classifier>postgresql</classifier>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.15.16</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <images>
                            <image>
                                <!--docker  run &#x002d;&#x002d;name mensosdb -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:3.0.8-->
                                <alias>oauthdb</alias>
                                <name>postgres:9.5</name>
                                <run>
                                    <env>
                                        <POSTGRES_USER>oauth_server</POSTGRES_USER>
                                        <POSTGRES_PASSWORD>password</POSTGRES_PASSWORD>
                                        <POSTGRES_DB>oauth_db</POSTGRES_DB>
                                    </env>
                                    <ports>
                                        <port>5432:5432</port>
                                    </ports>
                                    <wait>
                                        <log>database system is ready to accept connections</log>
                                        <time>20000</time>
                                    </wait>
                                </run>
                            </image>
                        </images>
                        <skip>${docker.skip}</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-containers</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                                <goal>start</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>stop-containers</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>stop</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.1211</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <unit.skip>false</unit.skip>
            <int.skip>false</int.skip>
            <docker.skip>false</docker.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>int</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>int</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <unit.skip>false</unit.skip>
            <int.skip>false</int.skip>
            <docker.skip>true</docker.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>uat</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <unit.skip>false</unit.skip>
            <int.skip>false</int.skip>
            <docker.skip>true</docker.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>pro</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>pro</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <unit.skip>false</unit.skip>
            <int.skip>false</int.skip>
            <docker.skip>true</docker.skip>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <keystore>${keystore.path}</keystore>
                <dname>OU=Development, O=Byteflair, L=Madrid S=Madrid, C=Spain</dname>
                <keyalg>rsa</keyalg>
                <storepass>password</storepass>
                <keypass>password</keypass>
                <alias>dev_oauth_jwt_key</alias>
                <skipIfExist>true</skipIfExist>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
            visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <user.timezone>UTC</user.timezone>
                </systemProperties>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                </includes>
                <skipTests>${unit.skip}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${int.skip}</skipTests>
                <systemProperties>
                    <user.timezone>UTC</user.timezone>
                </systemProperties>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${sonar.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${classifier}</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>byteflair</id>
        <name>Releases</name>
        <url>https://nexus.byteflair.com/repository/maven-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>byteflair</id>
        <name>Snapshot</name>
        <url>https://nexus.byteflair.com/repository/maven-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.six2six</groupId>
        <artifactId>fixture-factory</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Optional dependencies for using Spock -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${spock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- use a specific Groovy version rather than the one specified by spock-core -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
            <version>Hopper-SR2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: *but seems you can not configure the deploy plugin for them* Yes you can, can you post what you tried? If the artifacts with the classifier are attached to the project, they will be deployed automatically along side the main artifact. Do keep in mind that 1 Maven project only has 1 main artifact (with multiple attached artifacts), so if you want 2 main artifacts, you need to use a multi-module Maven project. Also note that once deployed, the file name is mandated by the repository, and will **always** be `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${classifier}`, that you cannot change.

Comment: @Tunaki just added my last POM test

Comment: I'm having trouble to see where the artifacts with the classifier are created and attached to the build. The only thing in the `mysql` profile, for example, is the integration tests run with docker-maven-plugin, but no artifacts are created?

Comment: you either create one or another artifact. And yes, the integration tests are run using a docker container to launch the corresponding database